# Conducting Statistical Analysis on Evolving Populations

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, evolutionary-algorithms

I am writing a paper on the evolution of altruism. To do so, I have written a computer program that simulates the environment and allows a population to evolve. Organisms are either altruists or are not altruists. Altruists will try to save organisms that starve on any generation, but their probability of reproduction is decreased by a parameter *p*.

My test was to conduct the simulation in ten trials with different values of *p*. For each trial, 5 simulations were run, each lasting 30 generations. Throughout, I tracked the proportion of altruists in the population.

The data tables are massive, but I constructed a summary by averaging the altruist frequency across each of the five exposures, which is shown here:
[image]

I've been told that I should conduct an ANOVA to compare each of the series. I want to test the null hypothesis of the altruistic parameter having no effect on the evolution of the population. How do I do that? It was suggested that I take the slopes of each value of *p* and then do the ANOVA, but I'm entirely unsure how to do so or what the requirements are?

Comment: Well, how did Axelrod and Hamilton do it? It's a replication of their experiment, isn't it?

Comment: I think you need to run enough simulations that ANOVA isn't compelling or necessary. I understanding the limiting behavior trends to altruism under competing games. So, whatever $p$ is, more of it gets you there faster that much is clear except we expect a much smoother gradient. 5 sims per quadrant simply isn't enough. Also whatever the color and number represent, showing them on the same panel is confusing.

Comment: His is mathematical, not statistical @AdamO

Comment: The assignment requires a statistical test. I simply don't know which one to do.

Comment: I'm dubious of this "requirement". Before finding a test you need a) a hypothesis and b) data. Formulating a hypothesis per a) may help you along. It's b) I'm worried about. This simulation study is *not* giving you data. Each cell is an estimate, and its precision is set arbitrarily by the number of MCMC iterations you choose. You can choose so many iterations there's 0 uncertainty in the estimate, hence no reason for a statistical test.